# MVC5 - Passing string from Controller to view - Exact same code returning different results

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am running the same code in MVC5 from 2 spots in my code and one passes my email address to the view and the other does not and I'm missing something basic!!!

Code1 (Works fine):
My vUsersSecurityQuestion class that DOES pass my emailAddress from the controller to the view:

```
public partial class vUsersSecurityQuestion
{
    public int userID { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string securityQuestion { get; set; }
    public string securityQuestionAnswer { get; set; }
    public string emailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller Code that WORKS (referencing the above ChangePWSeqQuestionViewModel as the model returned to the controller):

```
ViewBag.dropdownSecQues = new SelectList(db.vNewSecurityQuestions.ToList(), "securityQuestionID", "securityQuestion");
ViewBag.EmailAddress = model.emailAddress;
var secQuestions = from q in db.vNewSecurityQuestions
                  select q;
var userInfo = from u in db.vUsers
               where u.emailAddress == model.emailAddress
               select u;
var model1 = new ChangePWSeqQuestionViewModel { viewUserAdmin = userInfo.ToList()};
```

My LoginViewModel class (that does NOT pass my username (which is the same as the email address above) from the controller to the view:

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email:")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password:")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller Code (that does not work) referencing the LoginViewModel class as the model passed to the controller:

```
ViewBag.dropdownSecQues = new SelectList(db.vNewSecurityQuestions.ToList(), "securityQuestionID", "securityQuestion");
var secQuestions = from q in db.vNewSecurityQuestions
                   select q;
 var userInfo = from u in db.vUsers
                where u.emailAddress == model.Username
                select u;
 var model1 = new ChangePWSeqQuestionViewModel {viewUserAdmin = userInfo.ToList()};
  //Pass username and current password to view and force the user to change their password
 return View("ChangePWSecQuestion", model1);
```

My view:

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.emailAddress)
```

I am hoping I am missing something obvious.. been staring at this for 2 hours +
I get the hidden field when I run the first code, but not when I run the second. I can't figure out why?? They are being run form 2 different controllers.. the one that works is coming from a different controller (and has to redirect to the correct view folder). The one that doesn't work comes from the same controller, but the emailAddress just doesn't get passed back. Both LINQ (var UserInfo) queries return a single row of data...

Comment: Your viewmodel creation code sets a "viewUserAdmin" property to what appears to be a List<vUsers>. When you set a breakpoint in the controllers of each use of the viewmodel is the "emailAddress" property populated for all records in the collection?

Comment: @BluJai - Thanks for the response! I actually figured out 2 different ways of doing this (and they're both AWESOME!)... I'm still not sure why or how it worked some of the time and not all of the time... I will post my answer when my deadline is done.

Comment: what happens after the last posted line of your first (working) fragment? You didn't show, that a property `emailAddress` is set in either fragment, but in the second fragment it is evident, that what is passed to the view has an unset property `emailAddress` - if any.

Comment: @JürgenRöhr - Thanks for the response! I figured it out!!! Answer below.

Answer (score 0):

OK... I figured out two other ways of doing this, (but I still do not know why it only worked some of the time in the first place).

You can set a variable in your model directly such as: `emailAddress = model.emailAddress.ToString()`. I tried this before, but without the `ToString()`

```
var model1 = new ChangePWSeqQuestionViewModel { viewNewSecurityQuestions = secQuestions.ToList(), viewUserAdmin = userInfo.ToList(), emailAddress = model.emailAddress.ToString() };
```

Then in my view I was able to do either of the following and they seemed to work every time:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.emailAddress)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.viewUserAdmin.FirstOrDefault().emailAddress)
```

Three hours of my life I will never get back... hope it saves that much X1000 for others... so slick. I'm sure this is probably old news, but to me it's AWESOME!!!